# Does a nested transaction release the lock after method complete?

Tags: java, ejb, openjpa, websphere-7

I work with WebSphere 7 and OpenJPA.

Here is two beans and part of persistance.xml:

```xml
<persistence-unit name="ASAP_Main">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/ASAPDB</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
            <property name="openjpa.Optimistic" value="false"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ReadLockLevel" value="none"/>
            <property name="openjpa.WriteLockLevel" value="none"/>
            <property name="openjpa.LockManager" value="pessimistic(VersionCheckOnReadLock=false,VersionUpdateOnWriteLock=false)"/>
            <property name="openjpa.LockTimeout" value="20000"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

```java
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "ASAP_Main")
    private EntityManager em;

    @MessageDriven
    public class A implements MessageListener {
        @EJB
        private B b;

        @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
        public void onMessage(Message message) {
            b.processWithLock(message.getObject());
        ...
        }
     }

    @Stateless
    public class B{
        @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
        public void processWithLock(Object obj){
        em.lock(obj)
        ...
        }
    }
```

Does **processWithLock** release lock after execution?

Comment: Where does the `entityManager` come from? Please show your `persistence.xml`. Please add the complete source of `processWithLock`.

Comment: Unrelated comment, but ... All these annotations.  All this presumed reflection going on.  I'm just starting with JPA, but ... the performance tax for managing data this way seems like it should be sooooooo high.

Comment: @Beryllium thank you for editing my post, I added persistance.xml without entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MDB defines the transaction border, the EJB *B* just takes part in the transaction started by *A*. A *nested* transation is something different.

All database locks are held until the transaction commits or rolls back, which is when *A*.onMessage() returns. So **processWithLock** will not release the lock after execution, when called within a global transaction.

Comment: thank you for answer, should I put REQUIRES_NEW annotation if I want processWithLock to release the lock?

Comment: `REQUIRES_NEW` would execute the annotated method in a new, separate transaction. So yes, the lock would be released when the method returns. But the transaction of your MDB and the EJB are then independent of each other (one can fail and roll back and the other succeed or vice versa). Maybe that's ok in your case.